# smart wrapping - instead it's elements into few lines

Tags: word-wrap

my code is wrapping in a wrong way i want the whole thing to go under like this;

```
if (link.classList.contains('main-nav-link')) 
    headerEl.classList.toggle('nav-open');


//or like this 


if (link.classList.contains('main-nav-link')) headerEl.classList.toggle('nav-open');
```

instead it's wrapping like this

```
if (link.classList.contains('main-nav-link')) headerEl.classList.
    toggle('nav-open');
```

its just hard to read it. I tried wrap on/off/column/soft/hard.

I want the entire element to move down, not just a part of it, because visually splitting it into two parts often confuses me and creates clutter."